# Magento 2: Sort/Reorder checkout form fields

Tags: magento2, checkout, admin

Is there a way to reorder/sort magento 2 checkout form fields from admin. In admin I just find to display/hide fields for checkout form.

I want to sort like ( Move firstname to bottom or move any other field to another place )

So is there any option to sort the checkout form fields in magento admin or I have to go with coding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`Magento 2 didn't provide the checkout reorder/sort checkout fileds at admin side, you can reorder/sort checkout fields using code.`**

**Try the below solution,**

**`First way:`**

Override the **checkout_index_index.xml** file in your custom module or theme, and add the below code.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">MilkJarCookies_OrderDeliveryDate/js/view/shipping</item>
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="lastname" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">20</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="firstname" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">21</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

You can set the **sortOrder** as per your requirement for particular fileds.

**`Second Way:`**

**create a plugin for the function process() of the class LayoutProcessor, which is responsible of bringing the fields in checkout.**

declare your plugin in **di.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="custom_checkout_address_fields_order" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Checkout\Block\LayoutProcessor" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**And the afterProcess() function**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Checkout\Block;

class LayoutProcessor {

  /**
   * Position the telephone field after address fields
   *
   * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
   * @param array $jsLayout
   *
   * @return array
   */
   public function afterProcess(
      \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
      array  $jsLayout
    ) {

       //Shipping Address
       $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
       ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']
       ['children']['firstname']['sortOrder'] = 100;

      //Billing Address on payment method
       if (isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
           ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children']
       )) {
           $paymentList = $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
           ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'];

           foreach ($paymentList as $key => $payment) {
               /* firstname */
               $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                   ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$key]['children']['form-fields']['children']
                   ['firstname']['sortOrder'] = 100;
               }
       }

       //Billing Address on payment page
       if (isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
           ['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']
       )) {
           /* firstname */
           $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
           ['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form']['children']['form-fields']
           ['children']['firstname']['sortOrder'] = 100;

       }
    return $jsLayout;
  }
}
```